# SOLVED - Python requests api - Creation of valid JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, python-requests

Good morning everyone,

I'm trying to make a POST request to [that API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/content-cloud/rest-api-documents/op-documents-api-1.2-files-data-post.html). The error comes when I create a part of the data required to be sent.

```
    #urlUploadFile
    url = urls.get('urlUploadFile')
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}

    #sys.argv[6]
    payload = {
        'jsonInputParameters': F'{{"parentID":"{sys.argv[6]}}}","duplicateResolution ": "TimeStampSuffix"}}'}

    payloadJson = json.dumps(payload)

    #payload['jsonInputParameters']["parentID"] = sys.argv[6]
    #payload['jsonInputParameters']["duplicateResolution"] = "TimeStampSuffix"

    files = [
        ('primaryFile', open(fileName, 'rb'))
    ]

    print("Execute post Upload")
    response = requests.post(url, data=payloadJson, files=files, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(credentials.get('userCEC'), credentials.get('passwordCEC')))
```

I know there's an error on how I create the data of "payload", but I do not know how exactly I'm supposed to create the string and add the variable value into it. I create that and then use:

```
json.dumps(payload)
```

Using this, returns me:

```
ValueError: Data must not be a string.
```

Any suggestion on how could I create the "data" information in order to use it properly?

Thanks !

> Solution:

As [Rishi Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9345439) said, I do not need the "json.dumps()" and also I had an error at the creation of "payload", putting additional "}}" after the insert of the variable. After this two, the petition was completed successfully and I can continue with the rest of the code.

Thanks !

Comment: There is no need to do `json.dumps()` You can send your Python dictionary directly

Comment: @RishiDev Okay, I quit that and also realised that the payload formation was incorrect. `    payload = {
        'jsonInputParameters': F'{{"parentID":"{sys.argv[6]}","duplicateResolution ": "TimeStampSuffix"}}'}`

And now it's working :D thanks for the light !